# Best way of handling concurrent requests

Tags: java, architecture

I am working on an Authentication system (java based) that will authenticate users and create a session for them. This session is valid for 5 hours. I do not want the same user to have multiple sessions at the same time. For this reason, every time a user logs in, user details are stored in a table. Its primary key is email and the entry has a ttl of 5 hours or it gets deleted when an explicit logout happens.
If the user tries to log in once again, the attempt is denied as the table has an entry for that user.
So far so good. Now the real challenge happens when there are concurrent logins from the same user.
When a user tries to log in from multiple sources at the same time (assume a bot attack), the above logic will break as all the threads are allowed as all of them does not see any entry in the table for that user.

I am thinking of utilizing cahce like 'MapMaker from guava'. Write access to this cache will be in a synchronous fashion and every thread will have to acquire a lock to make an entry. This entry will be valid only for 3 seconds (by setting an expiry).

key = email
value = some dummy value

I am only concerned about the key to confirm that the request from same user is already under process and reject the rest.

But it can significantly impact the performance as writing to cache is restricted to only those threads which has acquired the lock.

I am interested to hear from you if there is a better solution.

Comment: Why not just use an actual SQL database?

Comment: instead of cache?. but again I need to deal with concurrency and an additional burden of talking to DB can impact the perf even more

Comment: 1. "I need to deal with concurrency" You have transactions, problem solved. Don't reinvent the ACID wheel 2. "additional burden of talking to DB can impact the perf even more" Do you _actually_ have a performance problem? How many logins is your system dealing with a second?

Comment: I need to deal with 50-60 logins/second. transactions may not be possible as we use Cassandra as the DB.

Comment: I ask again: why not just use an actual SQL database instead?

Comment: Well, it is an existing system as it does various other functions which need Cassandra. So changing the DB is not an option.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you change your other functions. I'm suggesting you use a SQL database for your session tracking in addition to whatever you use currently; this is fundamentally no different from your suggestion of using an in-memory data store.

Comment: got you. I'll keep it as a last option because there are complexities in introducing a new database. are you aware of anything else (in code) that can handle it?

Comment: Use some thread synchronization.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate solution, depending on your requirements is to get rid of server side state altogether. This is what tokens (like JWT) will help you.

User logs in, just give it a token with a ttl of 5 hours. No need to track it, no need to store it. User presents a cryptographically valid token, you know the authentication went ok.

User logs in again (lost the token, closed browser, etc.). No big deal, just give out another valid token. Is it really a problem to have multiple valid tokens given out? Since you don't have to store anything, I don't think it is a technical problem at least.

So unless you have some valid business concerns regarding "sessions", I think this way is much easier.

Comment: we are already using jwt token and we cannot issue multiple tokens to a single user.

Comment: Why not? Are resource usages bound to the token for example? Depending on why, it may be an option to separate login from whatever is causing you to not wanting to issue a second token.

Comment: We have a subscription-based system and cannot tolerate people sharing their passwords, where multiple people log in with a single set of credentials.

Comment: @Renjith This is incredibly unfriendly to your users and it's a shitty argument to be honest. If you would restrict a user from login in twice, what happens if they try to login from a different device but forgot to logout on the other? It's a deadlock!

Instead monitor logins and detect patterns of password sharing and alert.

Comment: @Bart it is not. We will respect the new session and kill the old one from the backend.